# Remove duplicate values in collection

Tags: c#, collections, lambda

I have a collection of longs `List<long>` myIds. I am populating the collection with id's. However I get some duplicates in the collection which I want to remove.

I have tried using `distinct()` on the collection but to no effect. Reordering and applying `distinct()` again did not help either.

What is the best way to remove these duplicates without writing custom logic?

I tried this:

```
mydIds.OrderBy(x => x).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: have you tried `mydIds = mydIds.OrderBy(x => x).Distinct().ToList()` ?

Comment: Do you have a more complete code sample? I have no problem removing duplicate `long` values from a collection via LINQ's `Distinct` call; no `OrderBy` necessary.

Comment: You need to reassing the result of Distinct to a list

Comment: @Steve I think that must be it. Codingjoe, you need to re-assign the result. It does not change the existing list; it creates a _new_ list.

Comment: I see that my English is not that sharp, got my post edited in lightweight, but in a more understandable format :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to re-assign the list again since LINQ does not change list in place:

```
 mydIds = mydIds.Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: Ahh I feel so stupid. I actually had it working with myIds.Distict().ToList();
I had my breakpoint on a wrong collection variable. :/

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively if you are using `3.5` and above:

```
var hs = new HashSet<int>(myIds);
```

The hashset will be populated by the list. If the list contains duplicate entries they will be ignored. No exception will be thrown.

Answer (score 1):

You don't reassing the result of the Distinct to a List object

```
List<long> id = new List<long>() {20,50,34, 20, 21, 45, 50, 900, 34, 20};
id = id.Distinct().ToList();
id.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
```